# How do I set the focus of a control in a Delphi TFrame descendant?

Tags: delphi, setfocus, tframe

So I have a frame with a control on it that I want to be focused when the user activates that form. The frame is created when the user first activates it and all that works fine.

I've tried overriding WndCreate and setting it there but that doesn't work.

Comment: The frame is created when the frame is activated?

Comment: Yea, I have a framework where the user clicks on a navbar item and it creates the module if it hasn't already been created. The modules are TFrame based.  When I say "activated" I simply mean the navbar item was clicked so the module gets created.